# Text starts from right side of the textfield in extjs

Tags: extjs, textfield

I wish that when a person starts typing in the textfield the text is populated from the right side. Think of it as right-justified. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `fieldStyle` property.

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {       
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',        
        fieldStyle:'text-align:right;',              
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false 
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/tags/extjs-4.2.1/include/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This time you were the first to answer :)